# semidirect product

Tags: lie-groups

Is it true that the semi direct product of two semi simple Lie groups is semi simple?

Comment: Yes, because if you have a general semidirect product $G=G_1\rtimes G_2$ of Lie groups, then solvable radical of $G$ is either contained in $G_1$ or it maps nontrivially to $G_2$. 

Answer (score 6):

Since a Lie group is semisimple if and only if its Lie algebra is semisimple, we may show
that the semidirect sum of semisimple Lie algebras is semisimple. Indeed, if $L$ is a semidirect sum of two semisimple Lie algebras $A$ and $B$, then we have a (split) extension
$$
0 \rightarrow A \rightarrow L \rightarrow B \rightarrow 0.
$$
However, every extension of a semisimple Lie algebra by a semisimple Lie algebra
is trivial (because the Killing form is non-degenerate, $L=A+A^{\perp}$)
, i.e., we have $L=A+B$, the direct sum. Of course, $L$ is then semisimple.